# Giving me error while trying to pass the string in constructor of a smartcontract

Tags: solidity, react

This is my Election smart contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Election{
    struct candidate{
        string name;
        uint votecount;
    }
    struct voter{
        bool authorized;
        bool voted;
        uint vote;
    }
    address public owner;
    string public electionName;
    mapping(address=>voter) voters;
    candidate[] public candidates;
    uint public totalVotes;
    function Election(string _name) public{
        owner = msg.sender;
        electionName = _name;
    }
    
    modifier ownerOnly(){
        require(msg.sender==owner);
        _;
    }
    function addCandidate(string _name) ownerOnly public{
        candidates.push(candidate(_name,0));
    }
    function getNumcandidate() public view returns(uint){
        return candidates.length;
    }
    function authorize(address _person) ownerOnly public{
        voters[_person].authorized=true;
    }
    function vote(uint _voteIndex) public{
        require(!voters[msg.sender].voted);
        require(voters[msg.sender].authorized);
        
        voters[msg.sender].vote =_voteIndex;
        voters[msg.sender].voted = true;
        candidates[_voteIndex].votecount +=1;
        totalVotes+=1;
    }
    function whoWon() ownerOnly public view returns(string){
        uint maxi=0;
        string memory winner;
        for(uint i=0;i<getNumcandidate();i++)
        {
            if(candidates[i].votecount>maxi)
            {
                maxi=candidates[i].votecount;
                winner=candidates[i].name;
            }
        }
        return winner;
    }
    function end() ownerOnly public returns(uint){
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}
```

This is the react code where i'm trying to pass the string value in election function after submitting the form.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import web3 from './web3';
import Election from './election';

class Conduct extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            owner:'',
            elename:''
        }
    }
    async componentDidMount(){
        window.ethereum.enable();
        const owner = await Election.methods.owner().call();
        const elename = await Election.methods.electionName().call();
        this.setState({owner,elename});
    }
    election = async event=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        <h1> wait for your transaction</h1>
        await Election.methods.Election(this.state.elename).send({
            from:accounts[0]
        });
        <h1>Yout transaction is successful</h1>
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.election}>
                    <h3>Enter the election name</h3>
                    <input type="text"
                    value={this.state.elename}
                    onChange={event=>this.setState({elename:event.target.value})}
                    />
                    <button>Held election</button>
                </form>
                <h1>The current name of election is {this.state.elename}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Conduct;
```

Error:-Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): *election__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3*_.default.methods.Election is not a function

Comment: Change `Election.methods.Election` to `Election.deploy` or something similar.

Comment: yes, I change this 'Election.methods.Election(this.state.elename)' to Election.deploy(this.state.elename) and now it is giving me this error - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot create property 'arguments' on string 'Indian election'

Comment: Change `Election.deploy('Indian election')`

Comment: To `Election.deploy({data: "0xYourContractBinaryData", arguments: ['Indian election']})`

Comment: Wow that's great It works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
await Election.methods.Election(this.state.elename).send(...);
```

To this:

```
const options = {
    data: "0xYourContractBinaryData",
    arguments: [this.state.elename]
};
const transaction = Election.deploy(options);
const receipt = await transaction.send(...);
console.log("contract address:", receipt.contractAddress);
console.log("encoded arguments:", transaction.encodeABI().slice(options.data.length));
```

You can also use this printout in order to verify your contract on Etherscan.